# Make sub-network accessible via a static ip of another network

Tags: networking, ip

Please forgive the nature of this question but I cannot figure out an efficient way to archive the following:

Someone is opening a store within a mall for example. This store has its own closed network with several network devices like ip cameras, a pos system, digital signage, etc. The stores network is connected to the internet via the malls internet connection, all stores are in fact. Since the mall only has one incoming internet connection from their provider, there also is only one static ip address for the whole mall, right?

My question is, what if one of the stores network components - the pos system for example - needs its own dedicated static ip address to communicate with a server for example. How can this be archieved since the mall provides the internet access for the stores? How can you statically access specific devices within another network with only one ip adress?

Comment: I would assume the following assumption is wrong... `Since the mall only has one incoming internet connection from their provider, there also is only one static ip address for the whole mall, right?` You need to contact the mall's IT for more info. They quite likely have a subnet assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there also is only one static ip address for the whole mall, right?

Wrong - the mall's router connects to the ISP's network and gets from
the ISP's DHCP server a dynamic IP. There is no reason for the mall to
buy a static address from the ISP.

You're right that the mall will have only one IP address on the internet,
but internally all the stores will get a dynamic IP address from the
mall's DHCP server. Normally the mall's router will be the DHCP server
for the internal network.

The mall's router does
[Network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) :

> Network address translation (NAT) is a method of mapping an IP address space into another by modifying network address information in the IP header of packets while they are in transit across a traffic routing device.

Graphically this looks like :

[image]

> what if one of the stores network components - the pos system for example - needs its own dedicated static ip address to communicate with a server

There is no problem here - the store will have its own router which will
create its own internal network and will be this network's DHCP server,
allocating IP addresses to the store's internal devices.

The POS device will have its static IP address within the store's network.
The store's router will need to be programmed to support this IP address
in its network.

You will have here a situation of double-NAT :

```
internet <-> mall router NAT <-> store router NAT <-> POS device
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since the mall only has one incoming internet connection from their provider, there also is only one static ip address for the whole mall, right?

Not necessarily. For IPv4, one address is the default, but a business *can* get more if it wants to pay extra.

It's not that an internet connection is inherently limited to one address – it's just that IPv4 addresses are *scarce* so a standard customer only gets one (or even zero) unless they really need more. But from the technical side, there is no limit on how many addresses can be routed to a line.

If the ISP provides IPv6, though, the mall will *always* have enough dedicated v6 addresses for every single device, even across all stores. (Unfortunately, that's only useful if all devices involved – the "PoS system", the store's own router, the mall's router, the ISP, the "server" – support IPv6; if not, they still have to use IPv4 like before.)

> My question is, what if one of the stores network components - the pos system for example - needs its own dedicated static ip address to communicate with a server for example.

*Generally* it can connect to servers without having a dedicated public IP address; that's only needed a) if the server limits connections based on IP address, or b) for inbound connections (e.g. from server *to* PoS system).

But in both cases, the whole issue can be avoided by running the connections **over a VPN tunnel** – which one *should* be doing for such security-critical communications anyway. Both the store as a whole (the VPN client) and individual devices are identifiable that way, and the tunnel is always bidirectional (unless deliberately set up otherwise) so connections from the server into devices are possible as well.

*(note: I'm talking about a private VPN hosted by the store's HQ, not a commercial VPN.)*